# Create a text file with each iteration of a python loop

Tags: c, python-3.7

I have a python script that runs a C program :

```
cmd = ["/Users/stordd/Desktop/StageI2M/C/forestenostre/grezza_foresta", "-w", "/Users/stordd/Desktop/StageI2M/Leiden/text_file/USA.txt", "-m", "5", "-e", "-0"]

    # Open/Create the output file
outFile = open("/Users/stordd/Desktop/StageI2M/Leiden/text_file/Output.txt", 'wb')

result = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = result.stdout.read()

outFile.write(out)
outFile.close()
```

It takes a text file as input and create a text file as output and I want to make a loop that would create a text file at each iteration without replacing the previous one. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

In the open function call add the "a" for append

```
outFile = open("/Users/stordd/Desktop/StageI2M/Leiden/text_file/Output.txt", 'ab')
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Thank you a lot ! Just little correction it was just 'ab' because I had an error: >ValueError: must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode